# How to upload my Python code to my WiX website?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, velo

I'm new to Python and web development. I've written a machine learning program in Python which can predict the future price of any stock. I've to upload this code to my website (which has been hosted on WiX). This is the link to my code: https://github.com/sunnysinghnitb/stock_market_prediction/blob/master/Predicting_Stock_Market_Using_Python.ipynb

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. If you visit the above link, you can see a graph plotted at the bottom of the page. I want this graph to be plotted on my website.

In line 19, you can see that I've used a csv file to read data. This csv file contains the data of stock price of "TATAGLOBAL" of previous years. I used this data to predict the stock prices of next years using LSTM algorithm.

Now, suppose, I've some csv files of different stocks. What I want to do is to create an application which will be able to produce the similar graph as shown in the bottom of the given link. Meaning: When the user selects a certain stock, the output on my website will show the predicted stock price for the year 2019 for that particular stock.

Kindly, provide some insights on how can I achieve this on WiX? Which programming language to use? Feel free to ask for further clarifications, if required. Finally, thanks for your help and support.

Comment: try to find an online python interpreter that allows you to embed it into other sites.

Comment: The reality is that this will be really hard to do without hosting the server yourself since you can't simply link the files locally and trust them to stay up to date - you'd have to keep updating the latest charts/spreadsheets onto wix.

Comment: Thanks, Hippolippo and KuboMD. Updating the files is not an issue. Suppose, I've a csv file containing the data of years between 2008-2018, say. This csv will predict the stock values of 2019. The next time I will update that csv is at the end of 2019 i.e., after one year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do not wish to host the page on another server and embed it as IFrame inside WIX site. 
So at WIX you can use only javascript both at the server side and client side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gal's comments Wix Supports npm libraries and svg display.

So if you can find an npm library that generates an svg for the graph that might be a consideration. For this specific question Gal's approach is probably your best bet.